# Scrapy Pipelines - How to create a variable in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scrapy, pymssql

I am trying to store my scraped data *(productid, category, name, description, price and timestamp)* on two separate tables of a Microsoft SQL database. One table named `products_tb` yields the `productid`, `category`, `name` and `description`. The SQL statement which stores the data in this respective database also creates a `productgroupid`. The `productgroupid` must be used to store the remaining data, the `price` and `timestamp` in the second table named `pricefluctuation`. The idea behind this is that I have one table with all the unique products and one table which yields a daily update of all the prices + timestamp of all of these products. All the prices and timestamps can then be grouped using the `productgroupid`.

I tried creating the second SQL statement, but I have no idea how I must create a variable from a `SELECT` so that I can use the result to insert into another table.

**pipelines.py**

```
import pymssql

class KrcPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymssql.connect(host='DESKTOP-P1TF28R', user='sa', password='123', database='kaercher')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

#       This part works

        sql_statement = f'''
                    BEGIN
                            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [kaercher].[dbo].[products_tb]
                                WHERE productid = {item['productid']})
                            BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO [kaercher].[dbo].[products_tb] (productid, category, name, description)
                            OUTPUT (Inserted.productgroupid)
                            VALUES ({item['productid']}, '{item['category']}', '{item['name']}', '{item['description']}')
                            END
                        END
                '''

#       This part doesn't work :(   

        sql_statement2 = f'''
                        SELECT productgroupid FROM [kaercher].[dbo].[products_tb]
                        WHERE productid = {item['productid']}    

                        INSERT INTO [kaercher].[dbo].[pricefluctuation_tb] (productgroupid, price, timestamp)
                        VALUES (  variable for the productgroupid?  , {item['price']}, {item['timestamp']})

                '''        



        self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
        self.cursor.execute(sql_statement2)        

        self.conn.commit()

        return item
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    producttype=scrapy.Field()
    timestamp=scrapy.Field()
    category=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**Database structure in MSSQL :**

kaercher.db

1. products_tb

   - productgroupid *(bigint)*
   - productid *(int)*
   - category *(nvarchar(100))*
   - name *(nvarchar(350))*
   - description *(nvarchar(1000))*
2. pricefluctuation_tb

   - productgroupid *(bigint)*
   - price *(float)*
   - timestamp *(int)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql_statement2 = f'''

DECLARE @productgroupid INT;

SET @productgroupid = (
                       SELECT productgroupid
                       FROM [kaercher].[dbo].[products_tb]
                       WHERE productid = {item['productid']}
                       );

INSERT INTO [kaercher].[dbo].[pricefluctuation_tb] (productgroupid, price, timestamp)
VALUES ( @productgroupid  , {item['price']}, {item['timestamp']})

                '''
```

This assumes that there is one product group ID per product ID.

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly, thank you very much!